# wtforms ReferencePropertyField set selected

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wtforms

Using the GAE-helper ReferencePropertyField to show possible groups that a user can be in.

How do I make it show the what group the user currently is in when editing the user?

The selectfield works fine, I can change the group of the user and the changes are written to the datastore, but I can't figure out how to set the current value when redering the form.

I have tried using

```
form.field.data = current_data
```

but with no luck.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `current_data` a string? If not try using `str(current_data)` to convert, I had a similar issue using either entity keys or ids as values on a `SelectField`.